# Chrome extension manage webRequest lifetime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am making an extension that needs to capture POST data directed to a site and once the site response confirms success, change some local data to reflect it.

The issue is, the POST data is located in requestBody from the onBeforeRequest event, while the success confirmation is in the onCompleted event. I understand that the lifetime of a webRequest should be managed using its unique requestId, but I am using an Event Page and therefore trying to avoid the use of global variables.

eventPage.js:

```
function continueListening(requestDetails){     
    function finishListening(completeDetails){    
        if (completeDetails.requestId === requestDetails.requestId){
            doStuff(requestDetails, completeDetails); 
            chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.removeListener(finishListening);
            chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.removeListener(finishListening);
        }
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(finishListening,{urls:["*://site*"]});
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(finishListening, {urls:["*://site*"]});
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(continueListening, {urls:["*://site*"]});
```

I decided to try nesting listener registrations for the finalized request in order to provide them with the scope to compare requestIds with the initial request containing the form data. This appears to work, but I am concerned about a potential race condition between the resolving of the webRequest and the registration of the nested listener intended to listen for it, leading to any number of useless unremoved listeners.

The other option I see is to store the requestDetails in chrome.storage.local and check them against the completeDetails once they arrive. My main hesitation there is that if for whatever reason execution is interrupted the local disk space could be polluted with unresolved requests.

Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: Unfortunately although I believed I was making an Event Page, I did not have persistent:false in my manifest. As I learned when I added it, Event Pages do not even support webRequests. The Event Page equivalent, declarativeWebRequest, seems to have died in the beta channel. So making it a Background Page seems to be the necessary solution.

Comment: I wouldn't worry, just check chrome.runtime.lastError. As for the alternative idea (using storage), simply add a timestamp to the data object and periodically clean up the "old" ones.

Comment: @wOxxOm After further testing I confirmed my code produces progressively more wild listeners, all checking every new completed request against their dead requestId without lastError being set. Thanks for the tip about using timestamps though.

Comment: Your desire to use an event page and not have global variables appears to be something that you should just dump as a requirement/desire. This looks like it would be much easier to deal with by having one set of `webRequest` listeners for that site, which all check a global record of which `requestId` they should be acting upon. The reduction in the overhead of adding and removing the different listeners is probably worse than just not using an event page.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, I ended up having two listeners. The first saved the initial request to `chrome.storage.local`, and the second for handling complete requests and loading up the matching initial request to execute my code on both of them. Although I thought this jived with event pages, it turns out it was moot because event pages do not support webRequest.

Comment: The only reason I planned to use event pages was because the Chrome docs say things like "developers should begin migrating existing background pages to this new model" which smells of desire to deprecate.